# Page loaded twice when trying to override jQuery Mobile default settings with touchOverflowEnabled

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

As specified in the global config options I am trying to override jQuery Mobile default settings using the script order as specified in:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

I am able to achieve this however when I navigate pages on an ios device(iphone4 running ios5) they seem to be duplicated and appear over the top of one another once you visit a few links, or click the back button a few times.

Here is my script order.

```
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // my custom script
                $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
                    //apply overrides to default settings
                    $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
                    $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
                    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
                });
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the example (to see bug view on ios device):

http://dev.solidstategroup.com/ssgwebsite/mobile/

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I have not come across this issue anywhere. Weirdly the problem can't be reproduced in ios simulator or in the browser.

I have taken all other scripts out to eliminate these.

If anyone can advise or think of a way to override the default settings in another way it may help others.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution for this was to remove the touchOverflow feature below.

```
   $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
```

Removing this parameter means touchOverFlowEnabled is set to it's default value of false.

This feature is apparently known to be unstable and as it states in the docs:-

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/touchoverflow.html

there are known downsides and the docs advise to use with caution (although this particular problem isn't listed).