# Page_Load is firing twice on mobile only

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, webforms

When my site is opened on iPhone / Safari (on Samsung - Chrome it doesn't happen) the Page_Load is firing twice:

- first time as it should be page.aspx?id=1
- second time with a very strange query string page.aspx?_=1369049780144

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Thank you, friends!

Igor

Comment: no extra hints? like code or something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery Mobile and trying to override default settings (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038624/page-loaded-twice-when-trying-to-override-jquery-mobile-default-settings-with-to))

I would also suggest checking for blank src tags in images. This can cause funny behavior like page reloads.